# ¿como puedo mejorar la estetica de la transición entre paginas en html de un link?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Cuando seleccionas un elemento en mi pagina para cargar el siguiente segmento no es nada estético, se pone la pantalla en blanco por un milisegundo antes de cargar, utilizando la etiqueta meta no mejoro las transiciones y ni el tiempo de carga entre paginas.

```
 <meta http-equiv="page-enter" content="blendTrans(duration=1)">
<meta http-equiv="page-exit" content="revealTrans(duration=0.5, transition=5)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recientemente se creó **Web Transitions API** con lo que puedes manejar las transiciones entre páginas.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/view-transitions/